# Open new Page withing a tab-navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, navigation, tabbedpage

Iam using a tab navigation and withing a page and want to open a new one.

In my app.xaml.cs I create the Navigation page:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPage());
}
```

In the RootPage I fill the Navigation:

```
public RootPage()
{
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        Children.Add(new TestPage1
        {
            Title = "TestPage1"
        });

        Children.Add(new TestPage2
        {
            Title = "TestPage2"
        });
        Children.Add(new TestPage3
        {
            Title = "TestPage3"
        });
}
```

This type of navigation works pretty well already and looks nice.
Now I want to open a new page within the TestPage3:
TestPage3.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DemoApplication.TestPage3">
  <Button x:Name="openSetup"  Clicked="ItemClicked" Text="open Settings"/>
</ContentPage>
```

TestPage3.xaml.cs:

```
namespace DemoApplication
{
    public partial class TestPage3 : ContentPage
    {
        public TestPage3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage4());
        }
    }
}
```

This also works but doesnt look nice.

The new Content loads below the original tab navigation and after it's loaded the tab navigation disappears - so the content of Page4 is kind of jumping around :)

In other apps like soundcloud they do the same but it looks way more smooth.

Is there any way to like shift the tab-navigation between the back-navigation more smooth?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to navigate within a tab, each tab should have it's own NavigationPage.  The TabbedPage itself should not be within a NavigationPage.

```
MainPage = new RootPage();
```

and

```
Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new TestPage3
        {
            Title = "TestPage3"
        }));
```

Comment: hello, i have a little problem with this. i have a login, signup and dashboard. The dashboard is the tabbed page so already, it's in a navigation page because the rootpage is the mainpage where you have to choose login or signup

Answer (score 1):

As Jason said: If you want to navigate within a tab while maintaining the tabs, then each tab should have it's own NavigationPage. The TabbedPage itself should not be within a NavigationPage.

This is how it's done in XAML:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new RootPage();
}
```

**RootPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns:Pages="clr-namespace:AppName"
            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="AppName.Rootpage">
    <NavigationPage Title="TestPage1">
        <x:Arguments>
            <Pages:TestPage1/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

**TestPage1.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName.TestPage1">
    <Button Clicked="ButtonClicked"/>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPage1.xaml.cs**

```
public TestPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage2());
}
```

Note that with this setup you'll have to apply `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"` to all the pages you don't want the navigation bar shown, like I do in **TestPage1.xaml**. Applying it to your `<TabbedPage>`, in this case **RootPage.xaml**, won't work.

Comment: hello, i have a little problem with this. i have a login, signup and dashboard. The dashboard is the tabbed page so already, it's in a navigation page because the rootpage is the mainpage where you have to choose login or signup

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Home : TabbedPage
{
    public Home()
    {
        var alphaPage = new NavigationPage(new ExistingAlphaPage());
        alphaPage .Title = "Alpha";

        var betaPage = new NavigationPage(new ExistingBetaPage());
        betaPage.Title = "Beta";

        var gamaPage = new NavigationPage(new ExistingGamaPage());
        gamaPage .Title = "Gama";

        Children.Add(alphaPage);
        Children.Add(betaPage);
        Children.Add(gamaPage);
    }
}
```